# How can I write "/*" in a kotlin comment?

Tags: kotlin, nested, comments

**How can I write `/*` in a kotlin comment in a span code?**

For example:

```
/**
 * Defines the route `/route/*`
 */
fun defineRoute() { 
    /* ... */ 
}
```

Right now, according to Kotlin, `/route/*` is the beginning of a [nested comment](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html#comments) (so the whole file is commented). I'm using `/route/{*}` for now but it's not a decent solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just close the nested comment:

```
/**
 * Defines the route `/route/*`
 */*/
fun defineRoute() { 
    /* ... */ 
}
```

This has the benefit of breaking once they fix the Kotlin parser, to be reminded to remove these.

Answer (score 0):

You could use HTML escaping, so in your example:

```
/**
 * Defines the route /route&#47;*
 */
fun defineRoute() { 
    /* ... */ 
}
```

should achieve the desired result since

`&#47;` escapes as a "/"

Comment: Almost right: in a span code (surrounded by grave accents), it doesn't work. (it displays `/route&#47;*`, not `/route/*`).

Comment: I assumed from the syntax that this was for a KDoc comment. Why are you surrounding it with grave accents?

Comment: To write code (just like in Stack Overflow's posts). It actually is a KDoc comment.

Comment: Ahh haha I see your point now.
So does this solution work for the context of your problem?

Comment: Then perhaps backslash escaping could help. Post the full comment and perhaps we could help more

Comment: I've edited the question with a more relevant example. Backslash escaping doesn't help, of course I've already tested it.

Comment: OP, update if this worked for your issue, I believe this could be relevant to other users as well

Comment: Using `&#96;` is not better, it displays a grave accent instead of a span code in documentation.

Comment: I see the problem. I'll see if I can come up with a decent workaround.

Comment: It looks like there is no solution for now. I'll consider adding an issue on github.

Comment: I add it here so we can track it. Someone added the issue a few days ago: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-28979

Answer (score -1):

you can add a backslash before the /* like this:

```
/* say something \/*
*/
fun defineRoute() { 
/* ... */ 
}
```